# Como eu crio uma visão sql com mais de duas tabelas?

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, moodle, sql-view

Como criar uma *view sql*, preciso pegar o nome e senha no BD do Magento que estão em tabelas diferentes, para fazer a autenticação no Moodle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei a query abaixo [neste link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/294275/):

```sql
SELECT ce.*, ea.attribute_code, cev.value 
FROM customer_entity AS ce 
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute AS ea ON ce.entity_type_id = ea.entity_type_id AND ea.backend_type = ‘varchar’ 
LEFT JOIN customer_entity_varchar AS cev ON ce.entity_id = cev.entity_id AND ea.attribute_id = cev.attribute_id
```

A query acima retorna os atributos do cliente, então teria apenas que filtrar o atributo (`ea.attribute_code`) referente à senha numa cláusula `WHERE`.

Mais exemplos de queries que retornam informações do usuário [aqui](https://gist.github.com/ticean/735798) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154451/getting-customer-info-from-magento-table-structure).

Answer (score 0):

A sintaxe para criar uma view é a seguinte:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW nome_da_view AS SELECT campo1, campo2, campo3 FROM tabela
```

[mysql documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)

Comment: E se for mais de uma tabela? É o caso do Magento.

Comment: Se vc conseguir juntar elas pode usar um `INNER JOIN`, caso não seja possivel é melhor editar a pergunta descrever isso com mais detalhes.

Answer (score 0):

Este código SQL criará para você uma view

```
CREATE VIEW nome_view AS SELECT * FROM tabela
```

Documentação: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp

Comment: Prefira citar a documentação oficial, w3schools não é muito confiavel. http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/692/w3schools-e-uma-referencia-horrivel-certo e http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 0):

A resposta do utluiz é bastante certa. Porém, há algumas coisas importantes para entender sobre *views* no MySQL. Aqui [neste link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-updatability.html) (em inglês), explica quando pode fazer um `UPDATE` para um *view*.

> It is sometimes possible for a multiple-table view to be updatable,
>   assuming that it can be processed with the MERGE algorithm. For this
>   to work, the view must use an inner join (not an outer join or a
>   UNION). Also, only a single table in the view definition can be
>   updated, so the SET clause must name only columns from one of the
>   tables in the view. Views that use UNION ALL are not permitted even
>   though they might be theoretically updatable, because the
>   implementation uses temporary tables to process them.
>
> For a multiple-table updatable view, INSERT can work if it inserts
>   into a single table. DELETE is not supported.
>
> INSERT DELAYED is not supported for views.

Resumindo, há certas circumstâncias que, fazendo um `INNER JOIN` num view, pode usar o `UPDATE` da mesma. Se usar `UNION` ou `UNION ALL` ou um `OUTER JOIN`, já não pode fazer um `UPDATE` ao view. Nesses casos, teria que fazer o `UPDATE` às tabelas diretamente.